# Letter from Home Office after tourist visa refusal review

Tags: visas

A few months back, my mum applied for a tourist visa, which was refused. I felt the case officer made mistakes, which were in clear breach of the Home Office guidelines, misrepresented and ignored positive evidence. Knowing that this decision cannot be appealed, I wrote to my MP stating clearly where I think an error has been made and why the decision to refuse my mum the visa was wrong.

This was back in July. After numerous exchanges with my MP's office, I got an email from my MP today saying "the case has been reviewed by ECM and they will contact my mum directly with the outcome". Today my mum checked her email and got the below email from the Home Office about a week ago.

Does this mean the initial decision has been reviewed and they have arrived at a different outcome? Does this mean her visa will be issued considering they asked her to resubmit her passport?

> Regarding Visa Application:  XXXX
>   For: XXX XXX XXX
>
> After reviewing your application, we are now in a position to reconsider the decision that was initially made.
>
> However, we require you to resubmit the following document in order for us to do so:
>
> Your valid passport bearing the passport number XXXX
>
> Please present a copy of this letter, along with your passport, to your nearest Visa Application Centre by the XXXX of November 2017 in order for us to assess your application.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> UK Decision Making Centre

Answer (score 6):

What the email means is that they are prepared to review the decision. In order to make that review they need to see your mother and her passport.

Technically it does not mean they have reached a different conclusion. They might conduct their review and still reject your mother's application. However it is unlikely that they would go to this much trouble if they were going to reject it again, and if they were uncertain they would ask for more information. Your mother may be interviewed, although I would have expected that to be stated in the email if it were the case.

I would therefore do as the email requests  with optimism (but not certainty) that the result will be positive.

Comment: Interesting. So they said "After reviewing your application, we are now in a position to reconsider the decision that was initially made" in the initial paragraph and then in the end said this "order for us to assess your application." Contradictory much?. Thought the same initially re your comment about not a certainty but then asked myself why they'd go through requesting passport and the arrive at the same decision (refuse) considering what they have said in first paragraph of letter. We will do as instructed either way.

Comment: @EricAnnohghan its not contradictory - the application they reviewed was the application to reconsider.  They've looked at that application and seen that there are grounds for reconsidering the original decision, and they would now like to proceed with the reconsideration.  That does not mean the original application has *been* reconsidered and a decision has been made, just that they are now in a position to do so.

Comment: @EricAnnohghan basically there are two applications - the visa application and the application for reconsideration.